# Hibernate not finding entity attached in session

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I"m using Spring MVC and Hibernate and MySQL.

I've got a code that basically does this

```
@Transactional("transactionName")
public Product find(List<String> allProductNames){
     for(String product: allProductNames){
         //find product with productName
         Product product = em.createQuery(hql).getSingleResult());
         if(product == null){
            //create product object
             em.persist(newProduct)
         }
     }
}
```

Since the save and search is a part of the same transaction and nothing is getting committed until it steps out of the method.  the query to the database to find product with productName is always returning null. How do I force hibernate to also search for attached objects in the session ?

I tried

```
SessionImpl session = (SessionImpl) em.getDelegate();
Query query = session.createQuery("searchproductnamequery")
                     .setParameter("PRODUCT_NAME","iPhone");
boolean found = session.contains(query);
```

But the above seems to return false aswell. What would be the right way of handling situations like these ? Shouldn't hibernate search for the attached session objects and the database both by default ?

The reason I don't want to commit is because I want to update the count attribute to the product before it gets committed.

I can create a map of products and then commit at the end but looping twice through a list of 100,000 productNames twice is very expensive.

If I knew the id I could've used session.get(id) but how do I search via property name ?

Comment: query.addEntity(Product.class)

Answer (score 0):

em.flush() after save did the trick.